# Использование Dispose в C++ вместе с WinForms

Tags: c#, c++-cli

Как правильно организовать вызов метода Dispose и возможно ли это?

Есть код С++, который в CWinFormsControl использует C# класс унаследованный от UserControl.

```
CWinFormsControl<MyControl> myControl;
```

UserControl в свою очередь унаследован от интерфейса IDisposable.

Пробую сделать в деструкторе C++ класса

```
delete myControl;
```

который вроде бы должен вызвать Dispose для MyControl. Однако происходит только вызов финализатора, но не Dispose.

Получается, что Dispose для объектов MyControl вызывается с флагом disposing = false. И как же в этом случае согласно паттерну удалять managed ресурсы?

Добавлю отрывки кода. Сам проект здоровенный. Приблизительно так. Может чего-то не хватает.

C# объект

```
public partial class DP_ViewFormWrapper : UserControl
{
    bool m_Disposed = false;

    /// <summary> 
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }

        if (!this.m_Disposed)
        {
            foreach (UserControl paramDiagView in m_ParamDiagViews.Values)
            {
                ParamDiag_Page paramDiagPage = paramDiagView as ParamDiag_Page;
                if (paramDiagPage != null)
                {
                    paramDiagPage.Close();
                }
            }
            this.m_Disposed = true;
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

C++ объект

```
class CDVMachineElementsView :
    public CRoot3DWnd
{
public:
    ~CDVMachineElementsView()
    {
        // Удаляем объекты закладок
        for (MapTabItr_t Itr = m_mapBodyTabs.begin() ; Itr != m_mapBodyTabs.end() ; Itr++)
        {
             delete Itr->second;
        }
    }

    int CDVMachineElementsView::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
    {
        m_mapBodyTabs[0] = new CWinFormsControl<DP_ViewFormWrapper>();
        CWinFormsControl<DP_ViewFormWrapper>* viewFormWrapper = (CWinFormsControl<DP_ViewFormWrapper>*)m_mapBodyTabs[0];
        if (!viewFormWrapper->CreateManagedControl(dwWinFlags, CRect(0,0,0,0), this, 0))
        {
            return -1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: код где? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/de612743-c04c-4222-b05a-3451dfc85966/dispose-in-ccli?forum=vclanguage а вот тут смотрел?

Comment: Там то вызывается delete для C# объекта, а у меня для template, который внутри содержит C# объект. Код добавлю завтра, сегодня уже нет под рукой.

Comment: Что мешает сделать так: MyDisposable^ m = gcnew MyDisposable();
m->Dispose();

Comment: Повторю вопрос: код где? Приведите [mcve]

Comment: код, говорит, недоступен. подождем до завтра, а потом закидаем его хедерами

Comment: Добавил код. Возможно чего-то не будет хватать для понимания - постараюсь объяснить.